# Can't count cells populated by a RegExMatch function

Tags: regex, google-sheets, re2

I am attempting to count the sum of a column populated by a RegExMatch function but using a COUNT function, eg `=COUNT(F2:F100)`.

The function that populates a cell with `'1'` is:

```
=IF(RegExMatch($E2,"SKU123"),"1","")
```

I can see `'1'` appear many times in the column but when I attempt to sum the column I get a zero answer.

Any suggestions for how I perform a better RegExMatch (or alternative) or way to sum the column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your formula from

```
=IF(RegExMatch($E2,"SKU123"),"1","")
```

to

```
=IF(RegExMatch($E2,"SKU123"),1,"")
```

and will work.

COUNT returns the number of numeric values in a dataset, and you were filling with strings. SO in your version it will always return 0.